# Optimising sorting time in half an hour interval arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting, optimization, momentjs

I have developed a small function that will sort array of objects that have 
**lastAccessedTime** datetime information into sortedData array that holds same informations but placed in half an hour intervals (preparedData is an array that will hold only start and end time interval information).

My question is: is this the best way to achieve expected result? As data array gets bigger the prepareData() gets slower so I need to minimise time to do this preparing. 
Created a small fiddle to checkout logic https://jsfiddle.net/mtcljiljana/nvfq6h9h/

```
const data = [{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:15:41Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:32:42Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:32:47Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:36:02Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:36:55Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:37:28Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:39:48Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:40:47Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:42:31Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:44:06Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:46:04Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:46:43Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:50:31Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:52:54Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T07:53:53Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:14:00Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:14:44Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:16:20Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:17:32Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:19:21Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:20:13Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:20:59Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:22:59Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:25:14Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:26:17Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"id":913,"cookieId":"WfP2r2jiq4xAKo9YziaV5winTllwY5HL","creationTime":"2017-11-16T08:47:15Z","lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:47:15Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T08:49:47Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:12:39Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:24:25Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:26:15Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:28:10Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:28:53Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:30:49Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:31:48Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:34:01Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:43:47Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:44:21Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:44:30Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:44:34Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:44:48Z","path":"/"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:44:54Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:44:56Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:45:09Z","path":"/"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:45:14Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:45:16Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:45:30Z","path":"/"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:45:35Z","path":"/login.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:45:38Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:49:31Z","path":"/settings/license.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:50:47Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:50:57Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:51:32Z","path":"/settings/license.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:52:06Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:58:55Z","path":"/concurrent_users.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:59:12Z","path":"/connections/qc.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T09:59:22Z","path":"/connections/rally.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T10:07:10Z","path":"/connections/rally.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T10:11:21Z","path":"/connections/rally.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T10:22:48Z","path":"/connections/rally.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T10:30:27Z","path":"/connections/rally.htm"},{"lastAccessedTime":"2017-11-16T10:34:10Z","path":"/connections/rally.htm"}];

const prepareData = (data) => {
  const sortedData = [];
  const startDate = [];
  const endDate = [];
  // transform GMT to local time
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.lastAccessedTime = moment(d.lastAccessedTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  });
  // sort dates in ascending order
  data.sort((a, b) => moment(a.lastAccessedTime) - moment(b.lastAccessedTime));

  data.forEach(d => {
    const start = moment(d.lastAccessedTime);
    let put = sortedData;
    let endMinutes;
    let startMinutes;

    if (start.minute() < 30) {
      endMinutes = 30 - start.minute();
      startMinutes = -start.minute();
    } else {
      endMinutes = 60 - start.minute();
      startMinutes = 30 - start.minute();
    };

    const startTime = moment(start)
      .add(startMinutes, 'minutes')
      .add(-start.seconds(), 'seconds')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

    const endTime = moment(start)
      .add(endMinutes, 'minutes')
      .add(-start.seconds(), 'seconds')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

    sortedData.forEach(itm2 => {
      itm2.forEach(itm3 => {
        const date = moment(itm3.lastAccessedTime);
        const min = moment(startTime);
        const max = moment(endTime);
        if (date < max && date > min) {
          put = itm2;
        }
      });
    });

    if (put === sortedData) {
      startDate.push(startTime);
      endDate.push(endTime);
      put.push([d]);
    } else {
      put.push(d);
    };
  });

  const preparedData = sortedData.map((data, i) => {
    const object = {
      startDate: startDate[i],
      endDate: endDate[i]
    };
    return object;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedData));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(preparedData));
};
prepareData(data);
```

Comment: please add a small example of the wanted result.

Comment: The current result is wanted result. Trying to achieve the same result with fewer lines of code + more fast

Comment: In fiddle you can see two console.log outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the array by using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string and take a hash table for grouping the same time slot.

```js
var array = [{ lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:15:41Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:32:42Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:32:47Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:36:02Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:36:55Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:37:28Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:39:48Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:40:47Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:42:31Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:44:06Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:46:04Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:46:43Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:50:31Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:52:54Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T07:53:53Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:14:00Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:14:44Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:16:20Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:17:32Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:19:21Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:20:13Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:20:59Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:22:59Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:25:14Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:26:17Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { id: 913, cookieId: "WfP2r2jiq4xAKo9YziaV5winTllwY5HL", creationTime: "2017-11-16T08:47:15Z", lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:47:15Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T08:49:47Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:12:39Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:24:25Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:26:15Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:28:10Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:28:53Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:30:49Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:31:48Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:34:01Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:43:47Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:44:21Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:44:30Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:44:34Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:44:48Z", path: "/" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:44:54Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:44:56Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:45:09Z", path: "/" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:45:14Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:45:16Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:45:30Z", path: "/" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:45:35Z", path: "/login.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:45:38Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:49:31Z", path: "/settings/license.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:50:47Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:50:57Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:51:32Z", path: "/settings/license.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:52:06Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:58:55Z", path: "/concurrent_users.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:59:12Z", path: "/connections/qc.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T09:59:22Z", path: "/connections/rally.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T10:07:10Z", path: "/connections/rally.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T10:11:21Z", path: "/connections/rally.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T10:22:48Z", path: "/connections/rally.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T10:30:27Z", path: "/connections/rally.htm" }, { lastAccessedTime: "2017-11-16T10:34:10Z", path: "/connections/rally.htm" }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

array.sort((a, b) => a.lastAccessedTime > b.lastAccessedTime || -(a.lastAccessedTime < b.lastAccessedTime));

array.forEach(function (o) {
    var slot = Math.floor(o.lastAccessedTime.slice(14, 16) / 30),
        key = o.lastAccessedTime.slice(0, 14) + (slot ? '30' : '00');
    if (!groups[key]) {
        groups[key] = [];
        result.push(groups[key]);
    }
    groups[key].push(o);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to optimize :

1/ Try to remove moment and use Date function instead.

2/ Try to remove/change the loop inside loop inside loop :

```
 data.forEach(d => {
    ....
    sortedData.forEach(itm2 => {
       itm2.forEach(itm3 => {
           ....
       });
    });
 });
```

Comment: removing moment is not an option (lead policy). I am not also satisfied with ` the loop inside loop inside loop` but not sure anything I tried doesn't give me the same result.

Comment: I get a 14 faster result just by removing moment (10ms vs 140ms for 10000 loop, see https://pastebin.com/puWhbnQg and https://pastebin.com/Pez5zhWr ). But the main problem is the loop imbrication